# Python continue Not Working Properly

Tags: python, for-loop, continue

I am writing a method using Python and I believe that the `continue` statement is not working properly. Can some explain to me what is wrong there?

The method code is below:

```
def xlToLinkedDt(lst1, lst2, name1, name2):
        logging.info(">> New iteration")
        dates1, times1, dates2, times2 = [], [], [], []
        for i, (dt1, dt2) in enumerate(zip(lst1, lst2)):
            if bool(dt1) + bool(dt2) == 1:
                name = name1 if not dt1 else name2
                issues.append("The %s date of trip no. %d must be provided." %(name, i+1))
                dates1.append("")
                dates2.append("")
                times1.append("")
                times2.append("")
                logging.info("Exiting loop")
                continue

            logging.info(Continued after bool condition.)
            raise AssertionError("Stop!")
```

When I run this code I get an error and the following logging in one of the iterations:

```
>> New iteration
>> Exiting loop
>> Continued after bool condition
```

The code is not supposed to log both messages, only one of them. Also when I replaced `continue` with `break` it worked well. What am I missing?

Comment: To break loop you should use `break`

Comment: The `if` block is reached and then not reached at successive iterations. You should consider using `break` instead

Answer (score 2):

> The code is not supposed to log both messages.

Yes, it is.

After your code executes *continue*, the loop moves back to the beginning of the block inside the for-loop, in the next iteration.  If the condition in your `if`-block is not met at the next iteration, you will get exactly the behaviour you describe.

```
In [5]: for i in range(10):
    print("Trying with i={:d}".format(i))
    if i%2 == 0:
        print("`i` even, continuing")
        continue
    print("What am I doing here?")
   ...:     
Trying with i=0
`i` even, continuing
Trying with i=1
What am I doing here?
Trying with i=2
`i` even, continuing
Trying with i=3
What am I doing here?
Trying with i=4
`i` even, continuing
Trying with i=5
What am I doing here?
Trying with i=6
`i` even, continuing
Trying with i=7
What am I doing here?
Trying with i=8
`i` even, continuing
Trying with i=9
What am I doing here?
```

As you can see, there is still a *What am I doing here?* printed after the *`i` even, continuing* notification, but it belongs to a later iteration of the loop.  If we replace `continue` by `break`, we get very different behaviour:

```
In [6]: for i in range(10):
    print("Trying with i={:d}".format(i))
    if i%2 == 0:
        print("`i` even, not continuing")
        break   
    print("What am I doing here?")
   ...:     
Trying with i=0
`i` even, not continuing
```

As you can see, it stops immediately because (by our definition), 0 is even.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I get >> Started method; >> Exiting loop
>> Continued after bool condition.

Answer (score 0):

You used `continue`, I guess you meant `break`.

`continue` will skip to the next iteration of your `for` loop. 
`break` will leave the `for` loop.

Try that :

```
def test():
    print("Function start")
    for i in range(10):
        if i == 1:
            print("Exiting loop")
            continue

        print("Am I printed or not ?")
    print("I'm out of the loop")
```

Then replace `continue` by `break` and see what happens.
Since `print("Am I printed or not ?")` is part of the `for` loop, it will be executed on next for iteration after "Exiting loop", if you use `continue`. If you use `break`, it will be skipped.

Comment: Yeah I obviously know that. I don’t think you understood the question.